# Make dotplot scale y axis as for histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

We are using dotplots in a classroom setting to introduce the histogram, because the binning concept is confusing to many students. So we start with the dotplot which is similar but more intuitive:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
qplot(x, geom = "bar")
qplot(x, geom = "dotplot", method="histodot")
```

[image: dotplot]

Because students do this on their own data, the code needs to work without manual fiddling. However the `geom_dotplot` seems to use different scaling defaults than `geom_bar`. The y axis does not adjust with the data, but seems to depend only on the size of the dots. For example:

```
x <- runif(1000)
qplot(x, geom = "bar")
qplot(x, geom = "dotplot", method="histodot")
```

[image: dotplot2]

How can I make `geom_dotplot` with `stat_histodot` scale the y axis exactly as it would do for the histogram, either by using smaller or overlapping dots?

Comment: From the helpfile:
"When binning along the x axis and stacking along the y axis, the numbers on y axis are not meaningful, due to technical limitations of ggplot2. You can hide the y axis, as in one of the examples, or manually scale it to match the number of dots." - seems you may have to fiddle after all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with the following workaround that shrinks the binwidth until things fit on the page:

```
# This function calculates a default binwidth that will work better
# for the dotplot with large n than the ggplot2 default.
calculate_smart_binwidth <- function(x, aspect_ratio = 2/3){
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  nbins <- max(30, round(sqrt(length(x)) / aspect_ratio))
  range <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE, finite = TRUE)
  if(diff(range) == 0) return(NULL)
  repeat {
    message("trying nbins: ", nbins)
    binwidth <- diff(range)/nbins;
    highest_bin <- max(ggplot2:::bin(x, binwidth = binwidth)$count);
    if(highest_bin < aspect_ratio * nbins) return(binwidth)
    nbins <- ceiling(nbins * 1.03);
  }
}
```

Examples:

```
x <- runif(1e4)
qplot(x, geom="dotplot", binwidth=calculate_smart_binwidth(x))
```

[image: plot1]

```
x <- rnorm(1e4)
qplot(x, geom="dotplot", binwidth=calculate_smart_binwidth(x))
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: The ggplot2:::bin doesn't work anymore with ggplot Version 2.1.0